# Automorphisms of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb k}$ over a algebraically closed field $\mathbb k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-curves, mobius-transformation

> Let's consider an algebraically closed field $\mathbb k$. Consider the birational map $\phi: \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb k} \to \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb k}$. How do I show that if there are $f,g$, homogeneous poynomials, such that $$\phi[x:y] = [f(x,y):g(x,y)],$$  then $\deg(f) = \deg(g)=1$? In other words, how do I show that $\phi$ is a element of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb k)$?

So far I was able to prove that $\deg(f) = \deg(g)$. Let me give you this part of the argument: Take $[x:y]\in\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb k}$ such that $\phi[x:y]=[1:1]$. We must have $$ f(\mu x,\mu y)g(x,y) -g(\mu x,\mu y)f(x,y)=0\quad \forall  \mu \in \mathbb k\setminus\{0\},$$
because $[f(x,y):g(x,y)]=[f(\mu x,\mu y):g(\mu x,\mu y)]$. Using that $f(x,y)=g(x,y)\neq 0$ we conclued that the above equation can be written as
$$ [\mu^{\deg(f)}-\mu^{\deg(g)}]f(x,y)^2=0\quad \forall  \mu \in \mathbb k\setminus\{0\}$$
and therefore $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$.

Comment: You meant $\phi$ is a [birational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birational_geometry#Birational_maps) map $\mathbb{P}_k^1 \to \mathbb{P}_k^1$.  And $\frac{x}{y} \mapsto f(\frac{x}{y},1)$ induces an automorphism of the function field $k(\frac{x}{y})\cong k(\mathbb{P}_k^1)$

Comment: I can see that the map $\frac{x}{y} \mapsto \frac{f(x/y,1)}{g(x/y,1)}$ gives me a automorphism of $k(\frac{x}{y})$, but i don't see why this help.

Comment: Automorphisms of $k(z)$ are compositions of $z \mapsto az+b$ and $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ ie. Möbius transformations $z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Yes I meant $\frac{x}{y} \mapsto \frac{f(x/y,1)}{g(x/y,1)}$ sry

Comment: Well, I agree with you. Classifying the automorphisms of $k(z)$ is equivalent to my question, but how do I prove that the Mobius transformation are the only automorphisms of $k(z)$?

Comment: You can say $z \mapsto P(z)$ is not an automorphism if $\deg(P) \ne 1$, Or You can think in term of zeros poles : $k(z) = k(h(z))$ iff $h$ has a single zero and pole on $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: What if $\Bbbk$ has characteristic $p$ and $f(x,y) = x^p$, $g(x,y)=y^p$?

Comment: @ZachTeitler That's a good point.  Now it really matters whether the OP means birational or just bijective.  The Frobenius $p^\text{th}$-power map is bijective on points, but is not birational.

Comment: Well, i mean bijective. But why in $char \mathbb k= p$  there is a problem? I don't see it.

Comment: @reuns On your comment are you supposing $\mathbb K = \mathbb C$?

Comment: It works for any field, but $\mathbb{C}$ is easier for the intuition. If $\text{char}(k) \ne 0$ then not all bijective rational maps are birational

Comment: @Hugocito The map given by Zach Teitler is bijective if $k$ has characteristic $p$, but it is not an automorphism because its inverse is not a morphism.  If you only insist that the maps are bijective, you don't necessarily get an induced automorphism on function fields.  In your title you say that you are considering automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1$, but in the body you only assume that $\phi$ is bijective: this is the ambiguity.

Comment: Nice! I agree that the map $[x:y] \mapsto [x^p:y^p]$ is bijective on a algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ and therefore my statement seems to be wrong, but i do not see where is my mistake. Can you point it out? Maybe I using characteristic zero without noticing.

Comment: @Hugocito Like I said, if you only assume that $\phi$ is a bijective morphism, it doesn't necessarily induce an automorphism on the function field $k(z)$.  Indeed, the morphism $[x:y] \mapsto [x^p:y^p]$ induces the map $z \mapsto z^p$ on $k(z)$, which is a homomorphism, but is not an automorphism of $k(z)$.  As reuns said, I think you want to assume that $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1$ from the start, as in your title.

Comment: Now i see my mistake. My proof is totally wrong because if $g(x,y) = y^p$ then $g(x,1) = 1$ and does not have degree $p$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just summarize what was discussed on the comment section.

A birational map $\phi$ is given by a rational function $z \to \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ with $f,g$ polynomials. The inverse is also given by a rational function. By this fact we obtain that $z \to \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is automorphism of $\mathbb k(z)$ and the [automorphisms of k(z)](https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/automorphisms-of-ktk/) are given by the Mobius transformations. Therefore $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
where $ad-bc \neq 0$.

If $\phi$ is rational and bijective (this was my original hypothesis) then $\phi$ is not necessarily given by Mobius transformations. The counter-example is given by $\phi[x:y] = [x^p:y^p]$ over a  field $\mathbb k$ of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Yes, you need the birational hypothesis in order to obtain the automorphism of $\mathbb k(z)/ \mathbb k$.

Comment: Is there a counter-example where $\phi$ is rational, bijective and not birational when $\text{char}(\mathbb k) =0$?

Comment: In the case of $\mathbb C$ all bijective rational maps are birational, because a rational map $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C} \to \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ is holomorphic and holomorphic bijections are biholomorphisms. We know that the biholomorphisms $P^1_{\mathbb C}$ are the Mobius transformations.